# Access token Facebook graph api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

After created an app on FB, I get an access token XXX

when I open https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes?access_token=XXX it does show all information that I likes fine.

but when I open to see from another user (who set those info public,such as https://graph.facebook.com/4/likes?access_token=XXX ) I got nothing but

```
    {
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

Can somebody expand to me why and any idea solve?

Comment: You have to get a user access token for user 4 for the likes to come back to you.

Answer (score 5):

You can not view the likes of a public profile, you have to ask for permission(user_likes) from the app to see this info.

---

Info on the [`user_likes` permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#basic_info)

> user_likes: Provides access to the list of all of the pages the user has liked as the likes connection

---

Example of Public profile(*sorry btaylor, but your name is on the docs*   )

https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor/likes?access_token=xxx

You will see an empty data set.

---

From the user docs, talking about the [likes](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes) connection:

> Read
>
> You can read the pages that a User has liked by issuing an HTTP GET to /PROFILE_ID/likes with the user_likes or friends_likes permissions. For example:
>
> https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes